# Running Selenium Chrome with extension - Chrome not reachable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I'm developing an app with selenium on an ubuntu EC2 instance. Therefore, there are no displays.

To start Selenium I use xvbf. This is what I used to install xvbf and selenium:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install -y unzip xvfb libxi6 libgconf-2-4 default-jdk xdg-utils
sudo snap install chromium

sudo wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

pip install selenium
```

Now, I want to open Selenium within python. If I run the following code, I can get source code from google webpage:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import time 

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
print("display started")

# now Chrome will run in a virtual display. 
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
#chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs',{"extensions.ui.developer_mode": True,})  # Trial for dev
#chromeOptions.add_argument('--no-startup-window') # This blocks running selenium
#chromeOptions.add_argument("--force-dev-mode-highlighting") # Trial for dev
#chromeOptions.add_argument("--system-developer-mode")  # Trial for dev
chromeOptions.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chromeOptions.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222") # If I don't put a port I get an error about some port
#chromeOptions.add_extension('my.crx')  # This blocks selenium
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
print("Selenium loaded")

browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print("Page loaded")
time.sleep(3)
print(browser.page_source)
browser.stop_client()
browser.quit()
display.stop()
```

However, as soon as I uncomment the line for the extension, I get an error: Chrome not reachable. I downloaded the extension from a github project where it stays that you must enable dev tools. Therefore I also tried adding the lines commented with "Trial for dev". These lines do not block Selenium initialization (e.g., if I uncomment them and comment the line for extension Selenium works), but neither I see that adding them have any influence on the extension working. I get the same error.

What should I do?

**NOTE**: I tested in a windows PC with a device, and without using pyvirtualdisplay the extension works and I can get google source code.

Comment: As you are using `pyvirtualdisplay` did you try adding `--headless`?

Comment: Yep, but still, not working

Answer (score 0):

The code was working under Ubuntu showing the window explorer too.

At the end I removed all configuration for webdriver and used firefox instead of chrome since the extension was in Firefox too. You can init firefox with a virtual display with no problem, and after you init firefox you can apply the extension. That worked for me!